# Redux wont update state when action is processed

Tags: redux, axios

My application is calling the action correctly as redux shows it gets the expected data it needs. The problem is it never stores the payload from the action. it is similar to my profile reducer and that works great.

This is the action

```
export const getCurrentFriends = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get("/api/friends")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_FRIENDS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: {}
      })
    );
};
```

This is the reducer

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_FRIENDS:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          friends: action.payload
        }
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your state a list, and for each API call, you add a new item in the list, with an object, with one property "friends" with the data returned?

Comment: that's the idea. it gets the info from the api call but does not update the state